# Compute the ring of integers

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

I need to show that $\mathbb Z [\alpha]$ is the ring of integers of $\mathbb Q(\alpha)$, where $\alpha$ satisfies: $\alpha^3=\alpha+1$. I'm having trouble doing so.

My first thought was to find the minimum polynomial of a general element $z=a+b\alpha+c \alpha^2$, but this became quite messy. So  I need an alternative approach. Can anyone help me find one?

Comment: The discriminant of $X^3-X-1$ is $-23$ which is squarefree. A theorem says that this implies $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha ]$ is the ring of integers.

Comment: (In the course notes, check page 16, above Lemma 1.41, it should help you)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a general approach, find the discriminant of $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ and note that this divides the discriminant of the ring of integers (in fact if a prime $p$ divides this quotient then so does $p^2$) and then you can use the Kummer-Dedekind to work prime by prime.

In this case, the discriminant is $-23$ so by my above reasoning you must have the full ring.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but I am not sure what you mean by the discriminant of $\mathbb Z[\alpha]$. I've looked through my course notes, but cannot find a definition for the discriminant over a number ring, only for a number field. Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: The discriminant of a number field is only defined in terms of a given basis. If this basis generates the ring of integers (as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module) then that is what we call the discriminant of the field. Different choices of bases may not give the whole ring of integers and differ by a square.

Comment: For a given basis $b_1,...,b_n$ the discriminant is defined to be the determinant of the $n \times n$ matrix where the $(i,j)$ entry is given by $Tr(b_ib_j)$.